# OutOfMemoryError when trying to add to ArrayList at specified index

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to do an insertion sort with an ArrayList of Strings:

```
private static ArrayList<String> sortList(ArrayList<String> list) {

        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String curWord, curOrdered;
        int comparison;

        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            curWord = (String) list.get(i);

            if(newList.isEmpty())
                newList.add(curWord);
            else {

                for(int j=0; j < newList.size(); j++) {

                    curOrdered = (String) newList.get(j);
                    comparison = curWord.compareTo(curOrdered);

                    if(comparison < 0)
                        newList.add(j, curWord);    // problem is here, heap runs out
                    else
                        newList.add(curWord);

                }

            }

            System.out.println(i);

        }

        return newList;

    }
```

However, I seem to run out of heap space when I try adding to my sorted ArrayList. My outer loop only seems to run once, but I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you keep adding entries from newList to newList.  Unlikely that you will ever run out of entries to add in that case.

Comment: Do some debugging, you have an infinite loop in there.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this using the debugger to get an understand as to what your code is doing at the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are in the inner `for` loop you add a new element to `newList`.  Since the loop condition specifies to continue while `j < newList.size()`, `j` starts out less than the size, and you add one to both every time, `j` never reaches `newList.size()` and you keep adding elements until the heap space runs out.

Comment: Yep, that's it, can't believe I didn't see it earlier! Thanks!